# what is wrong with my regular expression (\d.\s.V13\d+\s.N\d.\s.\w*)?

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
3 V1388832414 N1 G96ca813824e9c752da0d0000ffe8688c
```

And my reg is :

```
\d.\s.V13\d+\s.N\d.\s.\w*
```

but it do not match.
I try to say : one digit first and one white space and char V13 and any digit with one or more length and one white space and char N and one digit and one white space and any character with any length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have so many unnecessary `.`. This should be enough:

`\d\sV13\d+\sN\d\s\w*`

I'm not entirely sure why there are `.` in your regex. The `.` is used to match any single character and therefore your regex doesn't work

### WORKING DEMO

Comment: Not only unnecessary!

Comment: @Shombol-shagol Perhaps you had better read a regex tutorial. That's not what `.` means.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
\d\s*V13\d+\s*N\d\s*\w*
```

http://regex101.com/r/fE1dC3

```
\d match a digit [0-9]
\s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
V13 matches the characters V13 literally (case sensitive)
\d+ match a digit [0-9]
    Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
N matches the character N literally (case sensitive)
\d match a digit [0-9]
\s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\w* match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
    Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
```